# Python problem with type error : ""float object cannot be interpreted as integer". Can't return the value of function in "for" loop

Tags: python, function

I need to create function g(n) which gives a sum of range of decimal numbers  from 1 to n (including 1 and n).

And than I have to create a 3x5 matrix which rows and columns are function from g(i*j-2*i^pi), i and j are indexes of rows and columns. This is what I made so far:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(n):
    return np.sum(range(1,n+1)) 

M = np.ones([3,5])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        M[i,j] = g(i*j - 2*i**np.pi)
```

The main problem is that kernel says 'float' object cannot be interpreted as an integer.

Any help would be great, sorry for my bad english, i would like to say that coding is very new topic to me, so really any help is great. Thanks very much.

Comment: Welcome to SO! This title is almost meaningless--being more specific will make it much easier to get help. Thanks.

Comment: Change your title to something useful if you can :)

Comment: `i*j - 2*i**np.pi` for i,j=2,0 is equal -17.64995565 what should g return?

Comment: @splash58 that is what it should return, thank you

Comment: where do i change the name of title, i am sorry , i am new here

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your `for` loop you are passing `float` argument to the `g` function, which is then used as an argument to `range()`, which takes only `int`. Try:

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

def g(n):
    return np.sum(range(1,n+1)) 

M = np.ones([3,5])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        M[i,j] = g(int(i*j - 2*i**np.pi) )
```

EDIT:
Kind of guessing, but maybe this is what you're looking for:

```py
import numpy as np


def g(n):
    return np.sum(range(1,n+2)) 

M = np.ones([3,5])

for i in range(3):
    for j in range(5):
        M[i,j] = g(int(round(i*j - 2*i**np.pi, 0)) )
```

`round` will round the number, instead of truncating it, and raising `g`-s upper bound to `n+2` will ensure, that `n+1` will be captured.

Comment: thank you @grzegorz , now it doesent give me error but the value in matrix is not what it should be

Comment: Hm, it's mostly 0's, could you maybe clarify, what do you want to get there, by ```g``` function? Just maybe to add - ```range(1, n+1) ~ 1,2, ..., n```. Also ```range``` of negative upper bound will return blank.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot call `range(f)` where `f` is a float, that's what the exveption you get is about. I guess you should use `int(n)+1` rather than `n+1`.